# Process.waitFor(), threads, and InputStreams

Tags: java, multithreading, process, inputstream

In pseudocode, here's what I'm doing:

```
Process proc = runtime.exec(command);
processOutputStreamInThread(proc.getInputStream());
processOutputStreamInThread(proc.getErrorStream());
proc.waitFor()
```

However, sometimes `processOutputStreamInThread` doesn't see any output and sometimes it does.  Roughly, the method creates a `BufferedInputStream` of the command's output and sends it to a logger.

Based on what I'm seeing, I'm guessing that `command` need not have all it's output dumped into the streams fed by `getInputStream()` and `getErrorStream()`, thus allowing the stream to be empty.

The results of my trials are the following questions:

**(1)** Does `waitFor()` in [java.lang.Process](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) require the executed program's output to have been read before it returns?

The documentation only states:

> causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this `Process` object has terminated. This method returns immediately if the subprocess has already terminated. If the subprocess has not yet terminated, the calling thread will be blocked until the subprocess exits.

**(2)** Under what conditions do the streams provided by `getInputStream` and `getErrorStream` need to be closed and/or are they closed automatically?

The documentation only states:

> Gets the error stream of the subprocess. The stream obtains data piped from the error output stream of the process represented by this Process object.
>
> Implementation note: It is a good idea for the input stream to be buffered.

One [user reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129441/process-builder-waitfor-issue-and-open-file-limitations) that he had to close the streams himself, but I get an exception at least part of the time indicating that the stream is already closed when I attempt to do so.

**Edit:** changed `getOutputStream` to `getInputStream`, now present above.

**Resolution:** The problem ended up being that in certain cases the threads used to process  the output stream wouldn't run until after my very short-lived process had completed, resulting in the input stream giving me no data.  `waitFor` didn't do any waiting for the output of the executed program.  Rather, the program ran and terminated before any output could be gathered.

I used threads because I'm not sure how much output I was going to get on standard error and standard output and I wanted to be able to process both simultaneously, without blocking one or the other should only one of them have data available.  But, because my threads can't consistently read the executed program's output, it's a non-solution.

My final coded looked something like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdargs);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process proc = pb.start();
processOutputStream(proc.getInputStream());
proc.waitFor()
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If your external process expects something on its `stdin`, you MUST close the `getOutputStream`.  Otherwise you will `waitFor` forever.

Here is the [When Runtime.exec() won't article](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) from JavaWorld which describes different pitfalls of exec method and how to avoid them.

From my experience it's better to consume STDOUT and STDERR of child process ( until they EOF ) and then block in `waitFor`.  Hopefully at this point you won't have to waitFor long.

An answer to Kaleb's question.
Under normal conditions you shouldn't close the streams, however because you are `waitingFor` and for whatever reason it does not have a timeout, you may need to close these streams if you encounter some error conditions in the output and don't want to process child's output further.  However, whether the child program will terminate (crash) when it's STDOUT or STDERR pipe is closed at the other end is totally up to that child's implementation.  Most shell programs though, will terminate under such conditions.

I really wish `waitFor` had some meaningful timeout though and the `Process` had a documented way of cleaning up its resources when you've decided to abandon its monitoring.

Comment: Must the other streams also be closed if they are used? Are they implicitly closed when the process terminates?

Comment: @Kaleb I've added an answer to your question to my post.

Comment: Regarding the JavaWorld article, there is a bug with the final solution.  If a process terminates very quickly, errorGobbler and outputGobbler may not have yet run and consumed data.  The code should be: proc.waitFor(); errorGobbler.join(); outputGobbler.join();.  This forced the main thread to wait until the streams finish reading input.

Comment: would it be too much to ask for some to post a code example here?

Comment: what's the maximum time waitFor method waits to complete process?

Comment: @DivyangShah.  As there is no way to specify a timeout, in theory it may wait forever.  This is really one of the major problems with `Process`.

Comment: yes, we have to intentionally tell after some time.

Comment: "you MUST close the getOutputStream" thumb up. I would even say, if your process does not expect anything close it! I had an unattended wmic cmd blocking (on win2003 only), even if the process output and error stream were read correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is slightly counter-intuitive, but:

> getOutputStream     Gets the output
>   stream of the subprocess. Output to
>   the stream is piped into the standard
>   input stream of the process
>   represented by this Process object.
>   Implementation note: It is a good idea
>   for the output stream to be buffered.
>   Returns: the output stream connected
>   to the normal input of the subprocess.

I read that as this Output stream from the main process and is attached to the standard input of the sub-process, so when you write to getOutputStream().write() you are actually writing on the stdin.

Do you possibly want to use .getInputStream()?

> Returns:
>       the input stream connected to the normal output of the subprocess.

As for Process.Waitfor() the API docs say:

> causes the current thread to wait, if
>   necessary, until the process
>   represented by this Process object has
>   terminated. This method returns
>   immediately if the subprocess has
>   already terminated. If the subprocess
>   has not yet terminated, the calling
>   thread will be blocked until the
>   subprocess exits.

I would say the thread this is called in will be blocked until such a time as the process has finished executing - you may still be processing output at this stage depending on the other threads or they may have finished before your thread returns.

Comment: The `getOutputStream()` that I had in my question was a typo. It really was `getInputStream()` in my actual code and wouldn't have compiled because the processing function expects an `InputStream`.

Comment: I think you're exactly right about my threads still processing output.  Most of the time, when I ran in debug mode, everything ran successfully since everything ran much slower.  When running without the debugger, it would usually fail. I'll post my workaround later.