# p.waitfor() waits forever

Tags: java

i am trying to run commands using java program,but p.waitfor() function waits forever.What is wrong with the code?

```
import java.io.*;

public class doscmd
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
  {
    try
    {
      Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir");
      p.waitFor();
      BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      String line=reader.readLine();
      while(line!=null)
      {
        System.out.println(line);
        line=reader.readLine();
      }
    } 
    catch(IOException e1) {}


    System.out.println("Done");
  }
}
```

Comment: The program seems to work fine without `waitFor()`. Why do you need it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the directory large?  Maybe p fills up its output buffer and stalls waiting for a reader to consume something so it can finish writing out the directory listing.

You should probably move

```
p.waitFor();
```

to the end of the method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to access your InputStream and ErrorStream before you're calling `waitFor()`. You should take a look at that [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150723/process-waitfor-threads-and-inputstreams) too for more details on how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your directory structure is too large. Move your `p.waitfor()` to

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir");
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line=reader.readLine();
while(line!=null)
{
System.out.println(line);
line=reader.readLine();
}
p.waitFor();
```

I tried running running this in C:\programfiles works fine.