# Redirecting output of a process with Process Builder

Tags: java

I am trying to run plink in my own console window. I started by using Process.exec() and that worked fine. The I moved to using ProcessBuilder and now the output is not sent out until I kill the process.

My code looks like this:

```
    class ConsoleOutputThread extends Thread {

    public void start(String processName) {
        // this was old code: Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            builder = new ProcessBuilder("plink", "-ssh", "192.168.3.21");
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            process = builder.start();
            //this was old code: process = r.exec (processName);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
            try {
                process.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
            char    b[];
            b = new char[1];
            while(is.read(b, 0, 1)> 0) {
                // this is for debug, normally sent to console
                System.out.println("Got character: " + b[0]);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

So, when using Runtime.exec() everything worked fine. Now, with ProcessBuilder, the read function blocks forever (actually until I kill the process, when everuthing is spitted out). However, the error stream works, i.e. if I put a bad option I get the messages in the console.
I am probably missing something here and looking for help.
Thank you

Comment: Do you `flush()` your streams?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Process.waitFor(), threads, and InputStreams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150723/process-waitfor-threads-and-inputstreams)

Comment: Apparently the waitFor() creates the problem, the program hangs there. Without it, it works

Answer (score 0):

You've set the `plink` process to write its output to a pipe which is connected to the java process. Anything output by the `plink` process will be saved in an operating-system buffer until your process reads it. The OS buffer has a limited capacity,, and if `plink` writes too much data, then it will block until your process reads some data from the buffer.

Unfortunately, the java process waits for the `plink` process to complete before reading anything from the pipe. So, if the `plink` process writes too much output, it will block indefinitely.

You should change the java logic to read the `plink` process's output before calling `waitfor()`.

Comment: You are somehow right, except that the plink does not sent too much output, but it waits for another process to complete (ssh). It asks for a password and until it gets connected and authenticated it stays in waitFor(). So, if I comment out waitFor(), it will go ahead. However, the output of ssh ("root@192.168.3.21's password:")does not go to my input stream, it goes to the console from where I started the jar file (this in in Linux, in Windows I think plink is implemented different). So the question becomes 'How to redirect the output for a process which calls another process?'