# Perl Script through JAVA Error

Tags: java, perl

I am trying to run this perl script through java. below is my script

```
public class Log {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Process proc =null;
        try
        {
            String[] commandAndArgs = {
                "cmd","/c","C:\\Users\\myscipt.pl"
            };
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandAndArgs);
            int returncode = proc.waitFor();
            if(proc.exitValue() == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Command Successful");
                try
                {
                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
                    String line="";

                    System.out.println("Process Executed"+returncode);
                    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Process Executed"+returncode);
                System.out.println("Command Failure");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception: "+ t.toString());
        }
        finally
        {
            proc.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

So when i execute this script its runs perfectly. But as soon as i am replacing the script with below line

```
"perl","C:\\Users\\myscipt.pl"
```

It throws me return code 2 error. So, where am i wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl C:\\Users\\myscipt.pl");
```

Comment: There is no difference between passing as array "perl","C:\Users\myscipt.pl" and passing it as a String "perl C:\\Users\\myscipt.pl"

Comment: @Kushal Kumar, did you have perl in PATH variable?

Comment: @BatScream,Yes i do have

Answer (score 0):

You can't figure out what really has gone wrong when you get an error return code from a child process unless you read the child process input and error streams simaltaneously, and monitor them.

Importantly, you wait for a process only after you ask your parent process to consume the child process input/error streams, since the documentation of waitFor() says:

> causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process
>   represented by this Process object has terminated. This method returns
>   immediately if the subprocess has already terminated. If the
>   subprocess has not yet terminated, the calling thread will be blocked
>   until the subprocess exits.

And after the child process returns a code, you will not able to read its streams as you have done in the `if(proc.exitValue() == 0)` loop.

So in order to achieve the above, you could slightly modify the code as below, though i have not read the error stream of the child process, which you should ideally do. To include that you can refer to:

[Catching Perl exception in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736996/catching-perl-exception-in-java/25737181#25737181)

The modified code,

```
Process proc =null;
try
{
    proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl C:\\Users\\myscipt.pl");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    String line="";
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        }   
    int returncode = proc.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Process Executed"+returncode);
}
catch(Exception t)
{
    t.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Exception: "+ t.toString());
}
finally
{   if(proc != null)
    proc.destroy();     
}
```

Once you read the error stream of the child process, you would know what error has occured which made the process return that code.

Answer (score 0):

So, i got the solution. Instead of just putting

> "perl","C:\Users\myscipt.pl"

i replaced "perl" with full perl path i.e

> "C:\Users\Perl64\bin\perl.exe","C:\Users\myscipt.pl"

and it worked