# Invoke another Java Application through your application

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I need a piece of code that can invoke another java application and send two strings as parameters. And then get String (This is a JSON string) response.

```
process = new ProcessBuilder("XYZ", Address , Type).start();
```

In this statement I don't understand what `XYZ` means, and how to define a particular method of Java Application to be called through this `ProcessBuilder` statement.

Comment: `ProcessBuilder`'s [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder%28java.lang.String...%29) states this constructor's arguments are the program and parameters you want to execute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke another Java program (let's say it's called `programName` with arguments `programArg1`, `programArg2`), you'll probably have to use something along the lines of:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "programName", programArg1, programArg2);
Process process = processBuilder.start();
p.waitFor(); // If you need to wait until it finishes execution
```

Take a look at for instance this question to see how to read the program's output (in case it writes it through `System.out`): [How to redirect Process Builder's output to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16714127/851811)