# Unable to sync a single file using rsync on linux

Tags: java, linux, ssh, rsync

I have an application running on a Linux server.
While running, this app creates certain files and after they are created they are copied to a different server (also Linux) using the `rsync` program.
At first I was syncing the whole library using the next piece of code:

```
    private void sync(){
        try {
            String[] cmd = new String[]{"rsync", "--ignore-existing", "-Wre", "/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa", "/home/user/IntSrv/Sync/Observation",
            "user@some.server:/home/user/GenSrv/Sync/"};
            Process p = new ProcessBuilder().command(cmd).start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}}
```

It was working fine and all the files were synced.

Currently I am trying to change the code in order to sync single file at a time.
I have changed the code to:

```
private void sync(){
        String orgPath = "/home/user/IntSrv/Sync/" + F.getAbsolutePath().substring(F.getAbsolutePath().indexOf("Observation")).replace("\\", "/");
        String destPath = "user@some.server:/home/user/GenSrv/Sync/" + F.getAbsolutePath().substring(F.getAbsolutePath().indexOf("Observation"), F.getAbsolutePath().indexOf(F.getName())).replace("\\", "/");
        try {
            String[] cmd = new String[]{"rsync", "-avz", "/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa", orgPath, destPath};
            Process p = new ProcessBuilder().command(cmd).start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

Unfortunately, the files does not sync.
Here is an example for the `orgPath` and `destPath`:

`orgPath = "/home/user/IntSrv/Sync/Observation/2017/204/17d/06/SROD204G30.17o"`

`destPath = "user@some.server:/home/user/GenSrv/Sync/Observation/2017/204/17d/06/"`

I have printed out the `rsync` output on screen. While using the working code it prints out :

`sending incremental file list
Observation/2017/204/17d/08/BRIG204I18.17o
     966.11K 100%  111.26MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=0/6)
sent 966.40K bytes  received 36 bytes  1.93M bytes/sec`

While running the second one it prints out:

`Permission denied (publickey).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]`

How is that possible? Why would i have permission to sync the whole directory but not a single file?
What am i doing wrong? Can anyone solve this issue?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you use 'sudo' ??

Comment: Because it is not a root user. Anyway the problem was solved.

Comment: I mean that you don't need sudo, if you run as 'user' and sync files from '/home/user' you do not need to use sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `-e` flag, that will instruct `rsync` to use `ssh` with the ssh private key.

Change `"-avz"` to `"-avze"` and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You might get some clues from the output of rsync command. You can get this using: [process.getInputStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()). (See [How to redirect Process Builder's output to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714127/how-to-redirect-process-builders-output-to-a-string) for ways to consume). Also I'd check the obvious, do the files exist, and does the exact same command work on the command line? (I would have written the above as a comment rather than an answer but I'm a noob on here so dont have the required "reputation", anyway hope it helped.)