# Start a remote process using java

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ppp, sshpass

Machine A connects to a remote machine B using `sshpass` and  that remote machine B doesn't give `ssh` access to `root` directly so I connect to it through `user` and use `sudo` and I also have disabled password for the `user` when he does `sudo su`. When the commands are simple like `ls -lrt /some/dir` I get correct output for the command but when I start a server/shell script on remote machine (server takes no time while the script takes 1 minute to run) the output is shown but the bash doesn't return back to normal(i.e. it looks like it is doing some work but I know that the server has started/script has finished).

Command used :

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@192.168.0.3 "sudo ls /dev/ttyUSB*"
```

above works fine, I get the output and the bash is returned so I can write more commands and do stuff.

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@192.168.0.3 "sudo /root/path/server &"

sshpass -p 'password' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@192.168.0.3 "sudo /root/path/to/script/scriptTakes1Minute param1 param2"
```

But, the above doesn't work as expected. It looks like it is doing work but it isn't the bash is not returned and so I can't write commands further.

I can't share the script or the server program as it is company's code. But the server code uses UNIX datagram sockets to communicate.

```
/* Creating a UNIX datagram socket for Server Application */
        if ((sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
        {
                perror("server: socket");
                exit(1);
        }
```

EDIT 1:

When I tried

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@192.168.0.3 "sudo /root/path/server >/dev/null &2>1 </dev/null &"
```

the server program started correctly but the script didn't work as expected and didn't return the bash but as soon as I pressed `ENTER` the bash returned, I know it means something but don't know what.

EDIT 2:

I can't redirect output to a file as I don't know how much time will the command take to run in total it may take a minute or few.

EDIT 3:

I found something that will help a lot(I guess). The script that is kept on that machine B creates few processes in background and so the `sshpass` doesn't return until all those background processes are killed manually from Machine B. As soon as those programs are killed we get that output as well as the bash back.

EDIT 4:

The script creates 8 ppp sessions that run in background.

Comment: Try calling `process.getOutputStream().close()` and see whether it makes a difference.

Comment: I dont know how much time will it take so I can't close the output stream but the sshpass command is at fault here not java. Please help me with that or some alternative.

Comment: Closing output stream doesn’t stop the process. The process gets a EOF.

Comment: So when should i close the output stream? @KDM

Comment: You can put this just after the exec() call. Since a Control+C seems to make your app work - it looks like the app is waiting for some input. Sending a EOF might solve the issue.

Comment: But the process takes 1 minute to run so wont it stop it immediately without giving me the complete response that I want.

Comment: Hmm... how long does it take to try it? And if it works you can always try to figure out how it works :)

Comment: @KDM It takes 1-2 minutes for the process to run, it keeps on printing the output but I want the complete output.

Comment: Sending a EOF (closing getOutputStream()) doesn't stop the process. You should be receiving full output.

Comment: So basically you want to execute a command and get a bash once the command is finished?

Comment: Yes...it comes back for few commands but not for those I mentioned.

Comment: Can you give an example of the script you execute?

Comment: Edited the question, cant share much of the details.

Comment: Can you please try this `sshpass -p 'password' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@192.168.0.3 "sudo /root/path/server >/dev/null &2>1 </dev/null &"`

Comment: The `server` started as expected but I want the output of that script as well.
I have edited the question, please have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166731/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-shashank-singh).

Answer (score 4):

Simply need to use one more line of code `process.waitFor();` which will fix your issue:-

```
 process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(SHELL_COMMAND);
 process.waitFor();// add this line to complete execution of your shell command
 System.out.println("LLLLLLLOOOOOOOOOKKKKKKKK started process");
```

Comment: `IllegalMonitorStateException` occured, I am trying to solve it, was just letting you know.

Comment: @ShashankSingh, I have modified my answer with a different method. Try with this and let me know.

Comment: Still the issue is there. Thank you for trying. One more observation ,when I pressed `CTRL+C` then the output can be seen and it is the correct output which is expected. I don't know if it is something that is `sshpass` problem or `java` problem.

Comment: Just try to execute a `ls` command from java and check whether java issue or any other other issue. Also verify permission as well.

Comment: also comment out //process.destroy(); and check.

Comment: If you are executing a shell script check whether you have added `exit` in the shell script or not.

Comment: I am really sorry if I wasted your time its not `java`'s fault let me edit the question again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166455/discussion-between-shashank-singh-and-abhijit-pritam).

Comment: I am in office now. My office don't allow me to chat sorry.

Comment: You may delete your answer before it gets downvotes. I changed the question and it has nothing to do with java.

Comment: I have edited the question with a very important details in EDIT 3.

Comment: @ShashankSingh, Butter post it https://unix.stackexchange.com/ here. You will get the solution very quickly. And never change the whole question in future. Your original question is totally different from the current one. This question is nothing to do with Java anymore. Always post a different question if that is totally different from the current one.

Comment: Sorry. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 3):

If you want ssh to execute a command and return before the command completes, use the `-f` option, such as `ssh -f user@host myServer`. If it may produce output, you probably want to redirect stdout and/or stderr.

See the man page for details: https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#f

Comment: I need to capture the output in a `java` program. Will it be a best practice to first output each command in a file then read the file and delete it? The programs has many shell commands that I have to execute like this.

Comment: Yeah, you could redirect to files and read them in Java. Or you could use ProcessBuilder. It lets you launch external programs and get their output as Java InputStreams to read from (and in that case you wouldn't use `-f` with ssh).

Comment: I have edited the question with a very important details in EDIT 3.

Comment: From what you've posted, it looks to me like ProcessBuilder is what you want. For examples of how to run a program from Java and collect its output, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714127/how-to-redirect-process-builders-output-to-a-string

Answer (score 2):

So I created a simple server using express

```
express = require('express');

app = express();

app.all('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send('anc\n');
})

app.listen(9099, () => {
   console.log('server started');
});
```

and then executed using

```
sshpass -p 'vagrant' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no vagrant@192.168.33.100 "node /tmp/server/index.js 1>/tmp/log 2>&1"
```

It logs the output to `/tmp/log`. You can see the execution on below screenshot

[image: Execution]

As you can see I can capture the logs as well. If you have a list of commands to run then I would use a shell script and instead that script individual scripts can be logged to their respective files or spit output on main stdout and be captured in the `/tmp/log` we used in the command

**Working with sudo**

As you can see in below image it even works with sudo. But a word of advise, you shouldn't use `sudo su` because that would require a user shell and you want to use `sudo -u <user>` in your command which you pass to SSH

[image: SSH working]

**Edit: 19-Mar-18**

Based on your edit you provided a script

```
echo "First Line" 
ping 10.100.208.102 >/dev/null & 
echo "Last Line"
```

Now I assume you want the output `Last Line` as well and then you don't want to hang the terminal also. Below test command worked for me

```
$ sshpass -p 'vagrant' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no vagrant@192.168.33.100 "sudo sh /tmp/server/ping.sh 1>/tmp/log 2>&1 && cat /tmp/log"
First Line
Last Line

$
```

Comment: I need to start a script or server kept at `/root/some/path` so I need a `sudo` before it and I have removed the password when we do `sudo su`.
I can output the commands output using `redirection` to a file but I was hoping to get this way working as I can't figure out why is it that what I am trying is not working.

Comment: reply the actual command you used and I will tel you how to use it. I have used password less sudo while testing this and it works well

Comment: Please join this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166731/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-shashank-singh)

Comment: I have edited the question with a very important details in EDIT 3.