# How to check , if a service is running on linux machine using java code

Tags: java, linux, bash, unix

I want to check the status of a service running on linux.
On machine i use the command "systemctl is-active service-name" to check the status of services.And it gives the output as active/inactive(when service is running/not running).

I want to get the status of the service in java. how i do that?

I tried this..

```
String SERVER_STATUS = new String[]{SUDO_COMMAND, "systemctl is-active vpnd.service"};
try {
    final Process process = new ProcessBuilder(SERVER_STATUS).start();
    process.waitFor();
    InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line = null;
    System.out.println("status: " + br.readLine());
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {}
```

But `br.readLine()` is coming as null.

Comment: You only read one line while your process may display many line. See a working example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714127/how-to-redirect-process-builders-output-to-a-string

Comment: @Stephane

I mean br.readLine() is null

Answer (score 1):

Two things I found

- Please split the command
- Use absolute path of  the command

Example

```
String SERVER_STATUS[] = new String[]{"sudo", "/usr/bin/systemctl", "is-active",  "java-linux-sample.service"};
        try {
            final Process process = new ProcessBuilder(SERVER_STATUS).redirectErrorStream(true).start();
            process.waitFor();
            InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            //String line = null;
            System.out.println("status: " + br.readLine());
        } catch (Exception e)
          {
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is because there is an error running the application. Does your java process have permissions to run `systemctl`? Is it failing to find the service?

I would advise that you also check the exit value and then check the appropriate error stream.

---

For example on a Windows machine if I make a mistake in the cmd command

```
String[] SERVER_STATUS_COMMAND = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "echoo foobar"};
```

Your program will write

```
status: null
```

If we tweak the application slightly we can have the error stream redirected to the output:

```
final Process process = new ProcessBuilder(SERVER_STATUS_COMMAND)
    .redirectErrorStream(true)
    .start();
```

then the program would write:

```
status: 'echoo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

Comment: I tried with ".redirectErrorStream(true)", 
Now its writing ..
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified,

As the service is running as user "nobody", And the command will be executed by user "gateway". So i changed the command as below.
SERVER_STATUS = new String[]{"/usr/bin/sudo","systemctl is-active vpnd.service"};
And disabled password as below..
echo 'gateway ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl is-active vpnd.service' >> "/etc/sudoers"

Still facing same issue.